# Did Voldemort ever try to create another Basilisk?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, basilisk

In *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, we learn that:

> The creation of Basilisks has been illegal since medieval times, although the practice is easily concealed by simply removing the chicken egg from beneath the toad when the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures comes to call.
>
> However, since Basilisks are uncontrollable except by Parselmouths, they are as dangerous to most Dark wizards as to anybody else, and there have been no recorded sightings of Basilisks in Britain for at least four hundred years.

Given that

1. Voldemort is a Parseltongue, who is specially proud of his connection to snakes;
2. Voldemort successfully controlled a Basilisk as a teenager.
3. Creating a Basilisk is supposedly a very simple task involving a chicken egg and a toad.

Not only would having Basilisks at his beck and call, be an extremely effective weapon and terror tactic, certainly a Basilisk!Horcrux would *theoretically* at least, be a better idea than Horcrux!Nagini (almost immortal natural lifespan, plus way better natural defenses against attackers).

So did Voldemort ever try creating more basilisks on his own? If yes, what happened to them? If no, why not?

Comment: I don't know about reasons for not creating any more of them, but he certainly wouldn't be able to make it a horcrux, basilisks are known for having high volumes of that old horcrux destroyer; basilisk venom ;)

Comment: Haha, I did think about that, actually! but then I thought that since snakes usually don't poison themselves with their own venom, so I assumed maybe a horcrux!Basilisk would still be possible. But maybe not, that is also definitely plausible.

Comment: I think the venom definitely would not normally affect the basilisk due to the fact that they are immune to their own venom, but the soul/horcrux probably still wouldn't be able to handle it.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't seem in keeping for Voldemort to create a beast such as the Basilisk.  Voldemort was leading a cult in an attempt to overthrow the Ministry.  He used terroristic tactics to engage in a guerrilla war.  His primary weapons were:

- His personal power.  One-on-one, none could stand against him save perhaps Dumbledore.
- Secrecy. His followers were not publicly known, and could have been almost anyone.
- Speed. Like all wizards, Voldemort and his followers were capable of fast travel.
- Terror. People were ***scared*** of the Death Eaters and Voldemort.  Many people would do anything (even terrible things) to keep them away from their families.

A basilisk takes time to grow, requires a fixed location for the egg to be incubated and hatched, and is incapable of casting spells.  This would negate or mitigate much of the advantages Voldemort had: since it couldn't Apparate, it would need to be transported.  It would only listen to Voldemort, and could easily kill one of his other followers by accident, meaning Voldemort alone could safely transport it.  It would need care and a secret lair which would give the Death Eaters a major weak point - a fixed location that must be defended, that would weaken them if lost.  Finally, it would have been an affront to Voldemort's power.

The basilisk, since it could kill with a look, wouldn't be able to be always on hand (like Nagini was) for minor displays of Voldemort's ability to command snakes.  It couldn't have been easily used to scare people, only kill them.  If one of the Death Eaters screwed up and the basilisk killed him, it would make it look as if Voldemort wielded a weapon he couldn't control.

Finally, consider the utility of the basilisk: it can kill things.  It kills pretty much anything, and is a scary thing to fight.  Voldemort already had all of that, in spades.  He could kill entire teams of Aurors.  He could make many Wizards quake with fear at a glance.  He so thoroughly terrified an entire country that they *refused to speak his name for a **decade** after his apparent death*.  Anything a basilisk could do, Big V could do better.

Answer (score 4):

I've reviewed Pottermore, Fantastic Beasts, all of the Potter Novels and Accio-Quote and I've been unable to find any reference to Voldemort attempting to create another basilisk.

His powers would certainly be sufficient so there's no reason to assume he can't (nor that he didn't try), just that we don't *see* him try.

For the record, an adult basilisk is a relatively small creature and easily killed by someone with knowledge of their habits. It's only by dint of having remained alive for so long (in the safety of the Chamber of Secrets) that Salazar Slytherin's basilisk has reached such monstrous size.

Answer (score 1):

A basilisk would just not be very practical out in the world. If only looking into its eye kills, it would be very difficult to stop it killing all of the Death Eaters every time they were around it.